# Resources NotFoundException al intentar inflar un layout

Tags: android

Buen dia.

Tengo un activity en la cual lleno un `listview` por medio de un adaptador, en lollipop funciona perfecto pero en marshmallow y jellybean me aparece esta exception

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04006f

la linea en la q falla es esta

```
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_resident_dispense, parent, false);
```

¿porque sucede esto?. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Antes de intentar cualquier otra cosa, `clean`y `rebuild` tu proyecto.

Comment: Te recomiendo primeramente Clean y build de tu proyecto, si el problema continua agrega item_resident_dispense.xml

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente la razón es que no existe el archivo `item_resident_dispense.xml` por lo tanto no puede generar un Id dentro del archivo R.java

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04006f

un elemento dentro de `item_resident_dispense.xml` no existe o estas realizando un `setText()` a un valor entero!

---

Otra causa es que el archivo R.java que contiene las referencias de los elementos dentro del proyecto por alguna razón no se creo correctamente puedes realizar `Clean` > `Build` y probar nuevamente.